# C++ WINAPI Button Clipboard - Copy action

Tags: c++, winapi

I am a bit new to C++ but I know the basics and how to use it properly. I am just wondering how to copy to a clipboard in a windows application. I want 4 buttons to be able to copy a message when clicked and store it in clipboard. Here is the code for the button, the if statement is the action that is carried out when clicked:

```
case WM_CREATE:{

            CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Copythistext"),
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            12,60,10,20,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL
            );

            break;
       }



case WM_COMMAND:{      //this is where the button performs it's task 
            if(LOWORD(wParam)== ID_BUTTON) { 
        //this is where the task goes

       }
       break;
     }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Copying_Information_to_the_Clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Sequence of events:

```
void AddToClipboard(char* pszText)
{
int nStrLen = strlen(pszText);
HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(nStrLen + 1, GMEM_SHARE);
char* pCopyTo = (char*) GlobalLock(hMem);
strcpy(pCopyTo, pszText);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);
OpenClipboard(NULL); // or HWND handle instead of NULL
EmptyClipboard();


SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem); // hMem is handle to memory allocated with GlobalAlloc
CloseClipboard();
}
```

For the hMem, you usually do a GlobalAlloc(), GlobalLock(), copy string to the pointer returned by GlobalLock(), then do a GlobalUnlock() on the handle

Comment: where would i put my text that I want copied? sorry i am a bit new at this. Also, hMem is undeclared where do i declare it?

Comment: I improved the answer.  I cannot claim it works or I tested it because I did it from memory and without compiling or testing.  It would be slightly different for a UNICODE build.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxsonL don't forget error handling, as any one of those API functions can fail, especially `OpenClipboard()`, but also your use of a NULL clipboard owner **forces** `SetClipboardData()` to fail: "*If an application calls OpenClipboard with hwnd set to NULL, EmptyClipboard sets the clipboard owner to NULL; **this causes SetClipboardData to fail**.*"

Comment: Well, it's not my job to do everything, but to point the way. Yes, the user should do error checking.  I just saw the note in the API declaration that said "A handle to the window to be associated with the open clipboard. If this parameter is NULL, the open clipboard is associated with the current task."  IMHO, the documentation should have the note you noted further up.

Answer (score -1):

There is a curious way to send text from BUTTON to clipboard: via SetDlgItemText + WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK to STATIC with SS_NOTIFY (size of STATIC may be =0).